# Xcode 6 autocomplete failure (<<error type>>)

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, xcode6

I am developing an app with Swift and I started to experience a strange Xcode behaviour at some point. I do not exactly remember how it happened, but the autocomplete is refusing to work and for all of my variables the type is **<< error type >>** . I tried some of the solutions available here, but all of them did not work. What could be the issue for this frustrating behaviour, please share your thoughts if you have already experienced this problem and solved it. I already deleted the derived data and checked if some of my paths are not correct, but everything seems fine.

Comment: If you've already cleaned DerivedData, the next thing would be to try to find which line in your code causes this error and file a bug report...

Comment: Yeh, I wish I knew the line of the error.. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was about to give up and work without the autocomplete feature, I even reinstalled XCode but with no success. What I forgot to try was to delete the .xcuserdatad folder that can be found when you right click on the project and select the **Show Package Contents**, then open **xcuserdata** folder and  delete the **[Username].xcuserdatad** folder. It worked like a charm, the autocomplete is "alive" again and XCode works better than ever before. I hope this would help anyone with the same annoying issue...

Comment: this keeps happening on XCode 7. It is ridiculous to work like this

Comment: From my experience with Swift, I would recommend you to not use semicolons at all, especially when you declare instance variables if you want to reduce the number of source kit crashes.

Comment: I was getting so many source kit crashes once and nothing was helping me until I realized I have big commented code section outside of my class scope. After I removed it, everything went back to normal. 
XCode Swift autocompletion is a real mystery for me and I guess one of the reasons for this is that Swift is still a relatively new language and it will take some years to be stable.
For now I would recommend you to follow swift coding conventions and keep your code as clean as possible to avoid these source kit crashes.

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider, is that you could delete the DerivedData for your project. Go to Xcode Settings > Locations and open your DerivedData folder. There you can delete all the folders for your project. Restart xcode and see if anything changed. That was what solved it for me.

Comment: Is 2019 and I'm using Xcode 10.2, and this issue still EXISTS, and this solution still WORKS. Thanks!