# Xcode 9 Autocomplete Not Working properly

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, xcode9.2

[image]auto compete is not working properly like when i try to type some function like print it is showing autocomplete which is not regular.it is happing in every function. it was working fine couple of days before and suddenly it stop showing that auto complete and show such type of autocompelete is there any solution

Comment: Try to use this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504286/xcode-9-autocomplete-not-working-100-partially-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 Autocomplete Not Working 100% - Partially Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504286/xcode-9-autocomplete-not-working-100-partially-working)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.  The answers in the suggested link in comments did not work for me.

Try toggling the "Target Memberships" in the right "File Inspector."  This should work immediately without restart.

[image: Target Membership Toggles]