# Fixing Xcode 12.5 autocomplete

Tags: swift, autocomplete

As we all know, xcode has been known to cause autocomplete issues. There are [some fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504286/xcode-9-autocomplete-not-working-100-partially-working) like cleaning the build folder or disable autocompletion - restart Xcode - restart Xcode again and enable it.

In my case Xcode just [takes a lot of time to get the right autocompletion](https://youtu.be/BZo3jTGxU80). Has any of you had this problem and if how did you fix it?

I also cleaned the build folder and restarted Xcode and my Mac several times.

I am running Xcode on a Mac Mini M1 16GB

Comment: Xcode autocompletion keeps getting better with each update... try updating to Xcode 13 when it comes out